# How to ask about a person's child when not knowing the gender?

Tags: grammatical-gender

I know there are a few questions like this, but I have always had trouble remembering whether or not a person's child is a boy or girl. When I meet them again, it sounds awkward and/or brash to say "how is your kid?" or "how is your child?"

Is there a way to ask about a person's child in a gender neutral way that does not sound like an alien trying to communicate with new human friends?

Comment: If *How is your boy?* and *How is your girl?* are not awkward for you, then why is *How is your child?* awkward? Why do you think that sounds *like an alien trying to communicate with new human friends*? Clarify that, and we'll have a better idea what you're looking for. Otherwise, the question seems unclear.

Comment: 'How's the family?'

Comment: It seems weird that you could need to ask about a child that you know so little about - not even a name or gender, or one you have never met. Is there something prompting you to ask? Maybe you could ask about that - "*how did the school play you were telling me about go?*", or "*are you all over the bout of Chicken Pox you mentioned?*". Or some reason you particularly know about the child's existence - "*how are you managing being a new parent?*", "*how was your holiday to familyparkworldland, did you all enjoy it?*"

Comment: What is the status of your offspring?

Comment: Questions like this are off-topic here, but if you're interested then you should join the [Interpersonal Skills site proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92736/interpersonal-skills?referrer=36mFs0XUmsJEOCGBPsh_-g2)

Answer (score 3):

I ask this way: "How is your little angel?"

Comment: And then when the gender pronoun pops up, i.e., "She's fine" or "He's doing great", make a mental note or a note on your smart phone so you'll remember next time! ;-)

Comment: This is a great answer for a young child, but might sound sarcastic for a 17 year old Goth.

Comment: Alternative: "How is your little devil?"

Answer (score 2):

"How's the little one doing?"
("Little one" is a common term for the baby).
"Kid" or the less formal "kiddo" are also often used, especially as the child grows older, even into college age; it's not clear why you think that's so awkward.